# Google Cloud Platform VM instance issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I think I messed up really bad, but I am not sure. I was having problems with my VM so I went onto the google cloud platform and stopped and restarted my VM instance. I now cannot access my VM through the terminal or any other way now. I am scared that I have lost all my data from the projects and the labs now. Do you have any idea of what I should od or what happened? I have been looking stuff up online and cannot find anything. Maybe there is a google cloud platform customer service that I could contact but I could not find that either? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should not have lost data purely from a machine restart. It's possible that the restart has not restarted the services that you were using. It's not possible to provide much guidance because your question lacks any detail. It's possible the VM has been given a new IP address on the restart. You should be able to use Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com) to find the VM and reconnect to it through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the disks section, select your VM's disk and create a snapshot from it.
Open that snapshot and create a new VM from that snapshot (Better increase the boot disk size).
Start this new VM and try to SSH into it.

It is simply clone of your existing VM. You can see your data.

Comment: Please be more contructive with answers, adding screenshots and clear steps of what to do would be more helpfull for people who will face this problem in the future.